# fatal Exception when i try to get distinct values from the database table android

Tags: android

i have a table in the database named 'EMR_PT_REFERNCE' which contains patient reference details... there is a column named 'EPR_OUT_HOSPITAL' in the table which contains the names of the outside hospitals... 
i tried to get distinct values of 'EPR_OUT_HOSPITAL' from the table...if all the rows are filled up with values, then its working fine.. but if any of the row is empty then it triggers the exception and my application closed forcely...  please help

-----------------------------------here is the code--------------------------------------

```
  // to load out hospital/ clinic data into spinner
        private void loadOutHospitalListSpinner() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.v("this is inside load out hospital list spinner------------>","");

            try {

                if (getFirstRun()) {
                    sampleDB = dbAdapter.getDatabase();
                    setRunned();
                } else {
                    sampleDB = dbAdapter.getWritableDatabase();
                }
                Cursor c1 = sampleDB.rawQuery("select DISTINCT EPR_OUT_HOSPITAL from EMR_PT_REFERNCE",null);

                if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {

                    hospitalNameListArray.clear();

                    if (c1.moveToFirst()) {

                        do {
                            hospitalNameListArray.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("EPR_OUT_HOSPITAL")));

                        } while (c1.moveToNext());
                    }
                }
                c1.close();

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hospitalNameListArray);

                // dropdownlist
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                spnOutHospitalList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("CAT LIST ERROR IS: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

-----------------------------------here is the Logcat Error--------------------------------

11-29 15:26:38.572: D/AndroidRuntime(18519): Shutting down VM 
11-29 15:26:38.572: W/dalvikvm(18519): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.stpl.emr.login/com.stpl.emr.patientlist.PatientList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at com.stpl.emr.database.DataBaseHelper.getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.java:241) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at com.stpl.emr.database.DataBaseHelper.checkDatabase(DataBaseHelper.java:204) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at com.stpl.emr.database.DataBaseHelper.initialize(DataBaseHelper.java:61) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at com.stpl.emr.database.DataBaseHelper.getInstance(DataBaseHelper.java:93) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at com.stpl.emr.patientlist.PatientList.(PatientList.java:45) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871) 
11-29 15:26:38.582: E/AndroidRuntime(18519):    ... 11 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that:

Change

```
  do {
     hospitalNameListArray.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("EPR_OUT_HOSPITAL")));
  } while (c1.moveToNext());
}
```

to

```
  do {
     if (null!=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("EPR_OUT_HOSPITAL")))
         hospitalNameListArray.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("EPR_OUT_HOSPITAL")));
  } while (c1.moveToNext());
}
```